# How to arrange and group MySQL results

Tags: mysql, sql

I don't know how to start on this can someone please help me.
I have a table like this:

```
id      |code| shift     | rate
--------------------------
    1.  | AA | Morning   | 10
    2.  | BB | Afternoon | 20
    3.  | AA | Evening   | 13
    4.  | BB | Night     | 18
    5.  | BB | Morning   | 15
    6.  | AA | Afternoon | 25
    7.  | BB | Evening   | 15
    8.  | AA | Night     | 22
    9.  | AA | Morning   | 10
    10. | BB | Afternoon | 20
    11. | AA | Evening   | 13
    12. | AA | Night     | 18
    13. | BB | Morning   | 15
    14. | BB | Afternoon | 25
    15. | AA | Evening   | 15
    16. | BB | Night     | 22
    17. | AA | Morning   | 10
    18. | BB | Afternoon | 20
    19. | BB | Evening   | 13
    20. | AA | Night     | 18
    21. | AA | Morning   | 15
    22. | BB | Afternoon | 25
    23. | AA | Evening   | 15
    24. | BB | Morning   | 10
    25. | BB | Afternoon | 2
    26. | AA | Evening   | 8
    27. | BB | Night     | 3
    28. | AA | Morning   | 5
    29. | BB | Afternoon | 2
    30. | AA | Evening   | 1
    31. | BB | Night     | 2
    32. | AA | Night     | 2
```

I want to randomly select 2 morning, 2 afternoon, 2 evening and 2 night from the 'shift' column. And the sum of the 'rate' column of the selected values will be less than 100.
Also in the result set AA must appear four times likewise BB from the 'code' column.

Comment: Do you really have an `id` column with **full stops/periods** in the column?

Comment: you don't make it easy! I think we can put this in the class of problems that are is an np-complete - not a good fit for an RDBMS, but doable.

Comment: what have you done so far???

Comment: @ahmednawazbutt [What have you tried? is blocked for a reason](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/172760)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a valid result for a simpler problem.

- 1 morning, 1 afternoon, 1 evening and 1 night 'shift'
- sum of the 'rate' < 50
- AA and BB (the only possible values) must each appear twice

```
      
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;
    
    CREATE TABLE my_table
    (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
    ,code CHAR(2) NOT NULL
    ,shift VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
    ,rate INT NOT NULL
    );
    
    INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
    ( 1 , 'AA' , 'Morning'   , 10),
    ( 2 , 'BB' , 'Afternoon' , 20),
    ( 3 , 'AA' , 'Evening'   , 13),
    ( 4 , 'BB' , 'Night'     , 18),
    ( 5 , 'BB' , 'Morning'   , 15),
    ( 6 , 'AA' , 'Afternoon' , 25),
    ( 7 , 'BB' , 'Evening'   , 15),
    ( 8 , 'AA' , 'Night'     , 22),
    ( 9 , 'AA' , 'Morning'   , 10),
    (10 , 'BB' , 'Afternoon' , 20),
    (11 , 'AA' , 'Evening'   , 13),
    (12 , 'AA' , 'Night'     , 18),
    (13 , 'BB' , 'Morning'   , 15),
    (14 , 'BB' , 'Afternoon' , 25),
    (15 , 'AA' , 'Evening'   , 15),
    (16 , 'BB' , 'Night'     , 22),
    (17 , 'AA' , 'Morning'   , 10),
    (18 , 'BB' , 'Afternoon' , 20),
    (19 , 'BB' , 'Evening'   , 13),
    (20 , 'AA' , 'Night'     , 18),
    (21 , 'AA' , 'Morning'   , 15),
    (22 , 'BB' , 'Afternoon' , 25),
    (23 , 'AA' , 'Evening'   , 15),
    (24 , 'BB' , 'Morning'   , 10),
    (25 , 'BB' , 'Afternoon' ,  2),
    (26 , 'AA' , 'Evening'   ,  8),
    (27 , 'BB' , 'Night'     ,  3),
    (28 , 'AA' , 'Morning'   ,  5),
    (29 , 'BB' , 'Afternoon' ,  2),
    (30 , 'AA' , 'Evening'   ,  1),
    (31 , 'BB' , 'Night'     ,  2),
    (32 , 'AA' , 'Night'     ,  2);
    
        SELECT * -- for simplicity. In reality, we would need to name and alias all columns for this result to be usable
          FROM my_table morning1
          JOIN my_table afternoon1
            ON afternoon1.id <> morning1.id 
          JOIN my_table evening1 
            ON evening1.id NOT IN(morning1.id,afternoon1.id) 
          JOIN my_table night1
            ON night1.id NOT IN(morning1.id,afternoon1.id,evening1.id) 
         WHERE morning1.shift = 'morning' 
           AND afternoon1.shift = 'afternoon' 
           AND evening1.shift = 'evening' 
           AND night1.shift = 'night' 
           AND morning1.rate + afternoon1.rate + evening1.rate + night1.rate < 50
           AND LENGTH(REPLACE(CONCAT(morning1.code,afternoon1.code,evening1.code,night1.code),'AA',''))=4
         ORDER
            BY RAND() LIMIT 1;
            
            +----+------+---------+------+----+------+-----------+------+----+------+---------+------+----+------+-------+------+
            | id | code | shift   | rate | id | code | shift     | rate | id | code | shift   | rate | id | code | shift | rate |
            +----+------+---------+------+----+------+-----------+------+----+------+---------+------+----+------+-------+------+
            |  1 | AA   | Morning |   10 | 25 | BB   | Afternoon |    2 | 15 | AA   | Evening |   15 | 27 | BB   | Night |    3 |
            +----+------+---------+------+----+------+-----------+------+----+------+---------+------+----+------+-------+------+
```

(One of 721 valid results)